# Subtracting two strings in Javascript and type coercion

Tags: javascript

Why does Javascript do type coercion for the - operator and not for the +?

```js
str = "2"
console.log(str+str)
console.log(typeof(str+str))
console.log(str-str)
console.log(typeof(str-str))
```

Comment: When is the last time you subtracted, multiplied, or divided strings? How would the engine know if you meant "2"+"2" to be 4 or "22" ? Since it can not guess, it is always going to be concatenation. The others are for numeric operations so it can make the assumption and clean up the code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the only data type for which `-` makes sense is number. The `+` operator has meaning for string and number operands.

In JavaScript, in the general case an expression like `x + y` has to defer to runtime to figure out what it's supposed to mean. That's where the type conversion rules come in.  For `-`, it knows that the operands must be numbers so there's less work to do at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` operator is defined only for numeric subtraction

Answer (score 2):

In case of string `+` means concatenation. and all the other mathematical operator works just as normal mathematical operator (so the string is type coerced for these)

```js
let str = '2'

console.log( str + str )
console.log( str - str )  // 2 - 2 = 0
console.log( str * str )  // 2 * 2 = 4
console.log( str / str )  // 2 / 2 = 1
```

Links for further reading:-

[You don't know js](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html)

[Coercion explained](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839)